# How to log into a string? Is there a way to capture every console output into a single string?

Tags: java, string, logging, system.out, system.err

I use the `java.util.logging` `Logger` class, and
I would like to capture all messages on the console (not just the logs) and put them in a string (that I use later elsewhere). I did find a class that captures the `println`-s from `System.out`, but the logs go to `System.err` so I have to include those as well somehow. I have tried to capture both of them, but I didn't find a way.
I also tried to use handlers but I couldn't figure them out.
How can I solve this problem? Is there a way to capture every console output into a single string?

Comment: sounds like an XY problem, what exactly are you trying to achieve by doing this? It might be that there is a solution for that, instead of a solution for the problem cause by the other problem.

Comment: I have to put everything from the console into a json log file, and the class that creates it uses that string. Since then I was asked to let it go and now I am setting up Logback and slf4j.
Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.setOut(PrintStream ps)` method, like in this example:

```
public class Main{
    public static StringBuffer sb;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sb = new StringBuffer();
        PrintStream console = System.out;
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
            
            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                Main.sb.append((char)b);
            }
        }));
        System.out.println("Hello World!!!");//Go to the StringBuffer
        System.out.println("Hello World!!!");//Go to the StringBuffer
        console.println("Output is:\n" + sb);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Output is:
Hello World!!!
Hello World!!!
```